# Unusual unsigned short to bits swapping byte order

Tags: perl, bit

I'm reading in a stream of data, 64 bytes to be exact. I want to read 16 bits starting at the 480th bit of the incoming data. Unfortunately, I do not know what the incoming data type is, it's a bunch of random characters/boxes. Reading it in as an unsigned short (v), I get the number I am looking for, which for this example is 13.

```
my $satt_id = unpack("x60v1"), $msgdata); #$satt_id == 13
```

This results in $satt_id == 13, which is 00000000 00001101.

If I pull the data as 16 bits (b or B), the string does not reflect the value of 13, but rather is byte-swapped or reversed.

```
my $satt_idb = unpack("x60b16", $msgdata); #satt_idb == "10110000 00000000"
my $satt_idB = unpack("x60B16", $msgdata); #satt_idB == "00001101 00000000"
```

Why is this occurring? I want to alter the data and resend out the message, which would be relatively easy if all of the message elements were the same size (16 bits, just pack back as it was unpacked), but some are 6, 4, 2, and 1 bits. Should I just use little-endian b and then reverse? After altering the data reverse it back to original order and then pack it back as b?

Completely separate and not perl related, but this haunted me in a different utility. I just conceded by swapping the values in the Enum designation. It worked, just wasn't very viable when the amount of bits got higher than 4 (16 different values).

Thanks!

EDIT: I'm guessing this is just related to binary notation? Apparently starts from the right? So $satt_idb is correct, if you read right to left. So to make it more user friendly, just reverse, alter, then reverse again and repack?

EDIT2: Basically I'm trying to make a user-friendly method of editing messages coming through a data stream. As I mentioned in the comments, if I want to edit a single bit from 0 to 1 (which in the message represents something as true/false), I don't want the user to have to worry about editing the octet of data received, just select from a dropdown of true/false.

Comment: Why do you want the binary representation of the bytes anyway???

Comment: ikegami - is there a better way to alter / read in 2 and 1 bit "data" from a stream?

Comment: You can't read bits from a stream; reading is done in terms of octets (8 bits). `pack`/`unpack` similarly oriented around octets .

Comment: Ok, yes, I agree with that. The data is streamed in terms of octets. But let's say bit 7 is a true/false enum. What's the best way to alter it from 0 to 1 (false to true)? Unpack by octet, convert to binary, alter, convert back to octet, then repack as octet?

Comment: @BenWest if you are altering it, you likely want to use https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/vec.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it works with `v`, it means the data is in [little-endian byte order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness), which means

```
0b0000000000001101
```

is stored as

```
0b00001101 0b00000000
```

which is what you got.

---

> *Should I just use little-endian b and then reverse?*

No. You are likely doing something incorrect if you are converting the numbers to a text representation (binary).

If you did somehow want the binary representation of the number, you could use

```
sprintf("%16b", $num)
```

Comment: I guess I need to read up on bit storage. How does 0b00001101 0b00000000 == 10110000 00000000?

Comment: It's not. You're using inconsistent notation. You are displaying the least-significant bit first for some of those numbers, and the most-significant bit first for another. I've never encountered anyone using the least-significant bit first in the 30 years I've been programming, so I repeat (using most-significant bit first): 0b00001101 0b00000000 is how the the 16-bit integer thirteen (13, 0xD, 0b1101) is stored using LE byte order. 0b00001101 |  (0b00000000 << 8) = 13

Comment: Ah, it looks like I'm confusing LE/BE byte order and LS/MS bit first. So the correct data is coming out as MS bit first with LE byte order, which is B16 (MS bit first), not b16 (LS bit first), but it's LE byte order regardless.

Comment: The LE byte ordering and MS bit order makes a lot more sense with the example you gave. Thank you!

Comment: Remember that in memory, you have two bytes in some order. There are no bits; so bit order is a purely artificial concept used when representing a number. Just like writing twelve as 12 instead of 21 is purely convention. The point is that only LE vs BE byte order matter when talking about how a number is stored, not bit order.